# How Many .NET DataSources should I have?

Tags: .net, database, ado.net, datasource

I'm fairly new to database programming in .NET.

If I want to call several existing queries from the same database for different tasks, should I have one `DataSource` per database, per database connection, or per query?

Comment: Can you clarify the terms you're using here - do you mean "DataSource" as in a SqlConnection, or are you talking about something different?

Comment: I mean DataSource as in Data->[Sql,Access,Object,XML]DataSource in the ASP.NET Toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One per resultset, in other words one per query.